# Quickfixj- Custom FIX msg - 35=F not working for Multileg

Tags: quickfixj

I am using quickfixJ 2.3
To parse the FIX message , we have used
MessageUtils.parse(msgFactory,dd,inPutFixMsg, false)
I am able to place the list order ,multileg - 35= AB, AC order.
Now when I want to cancel the multileg order created by AB,
I just replaced 35=F, added 41 tag.
Now I am getting error while parsing in Message.parse : tag 600 appears more than once.

I am interested to know ,the other cancel( new order cancel, future cancel) working fine. Even I have  mentioned the dd, then still why m I getting the error?
Or is there any other approach ?

Comment: Why are you using `MessageUtils.parse`?  Either you're using QF for an unusual purpose, or you didn't read the docs.

Comment: We have provided the facility to user to enter direct Fix message in free form .  Ex : in text area user can enter the direct fix message in sequence like 8=FIX.4.4|9=352|35=F|11=xyz11111|41=oldOrDerNumner|55=abcz1-f2|....555=2|600=abcz1|608=abcd|624=1... likewise,he can enter the direct Fix message for for full multileg order. Consider herr pipe as soh character. Since we are taking the direct Fix message , we use parse  to valodate against dictionary. This is working fine for simple cancel orders. This issue is coming only for F with repeatingGroup.

Comment: That sounds like a dreadful idea.  If nothing else, you'll be doing a lot of support calls for users who can't figure out their FIX mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just change the message type (tag 35) and assume all the other tags are going to be compatible!

AB and F messages have different tags in their body.  They are totally different messages!

The amount of stuff about FIX that you need to know exceeds what is appropriate for a StackOverflow answer.  You really need to read some docs about how FIX messages are structured and decoded.

Comment: In such case , what approach to be followed to cancel(F) the MultilegOrder . Considering raw fix Message  as mentioned in question. This is our requirement

Comment: Read your counterparty's documentation about what they expect in the "F" messages that you send them.

Comment: They are expecting the same tags like normal.OrderCancelRequest. then how do we can parse such raw Fix message ? Do we supposed to build the logic instead of using MessageUtils.parse

Comment: Yes, you should build the message with logic.  I don't think I have ever used MessageUtils.parse in production app code, and I can't think of a good reason to do that.